# Magento 2 constructor error

Tags: magento2

I am facing the below error in controller file, any idea what's need to be corrected,
this looks like a quick fix

Missed required argument resultPageFactory in parent::__construct call. File: /home/customer/www/staging.site.com/public_html/app/code/Bg/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index.php

```
 <?php
    /**
     *
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    
    namespace Bg\Checkout\Controller\Cart;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
    
    class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
         */
        protected $resultPageFactory;
    
        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
         * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator
         * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
         * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
         * @codeCoverageIgnore
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ) {
            parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $resultPageFactory,
                $scopeConfig,
                $checkoutSession,
                $storeManager,
                $formKeyValidator,
                $cart
            );
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->deleteWrongQuoteItems($cart);
        }
        
        private function deleteWrongQuoteItems() {
            $om = $this->_objectManager;
            $cart = $om->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
            $customerSession = $om->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
            if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $group = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
                if($group==2 || $group==4 || $group==1) {
                    $cartQuote = $cart->getQuote();
                    $cartData = $cartQuote->getAllItems();
                    if(count($cartData)==0) {
                        $cart->truncate();
                        $cart->saveQuote();
                    }else{
                        $resource = $om->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
                        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
                        if($group==1) {
                            $sql = "DELETE qi FROM mgn_quote_item qi
                            JOIN mgn_quote q ON q.entity_id = qi.quote_id
                            JOIN mgn_catalog_category_product pc ON pc.product_id = qi.product_id
                            WHERE q.customer_group_id = 1
                            AND (pc.category_id = 5 OR pc.category_id = 6)
                            AND qi.quote_id = ?";
    
                        } else if($group==2) {
    
                            $sql = "DELETE qi FROM mgn_quote_item qi
                            JOIN mgn_quote q ON q.entity_id = qi.quote_id
                            JOIN mgn_catalog_category_product pc ON pc.product_id = qi.product_id
                            WHERE q.customer_group_id = 2
                            AND (pc.category_id = 3 OR pc.category_id = 6)
                            AND qi.quote_id = ?";
    
                        } else if($group==4) {
    
                            $sql = "DELETE qi FROM mgn_quote_item qi
                            JOIN mgn_quote q ON q.entity_id = qi.quote_id
                            JOIN mgn_catalog_category_product pc ON pc.product_id = qi.product_id
                            WHERE q.customer_group_id = 4
                            AND (pc.category_id = 3 OR pc.category_id = 5)
                            AND qi.quote_id = ?";
    
                        }
                        $result = $connection->query($sql,$cartQuote->getId());
                        if($result->rowCount()>0) {
                            $cartQuote->collectTotals()->save();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Shopping cart display action
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Shopping Cart'));
            return $resultPage;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent constructor arguments are fine but in wrong placements. Update parent constructor calling to this:

```
parent::__construct(
$context, 
$scopeConfig, 
$checkoutSession, 
$storeManager, 
$formKeyValidator, 
$cart, 
$resultPageFactory
);
```

This should work

Comment: $om = $this->_objectManager;  Is this code can throw error ?

Comment: No, this, $this->_objectManager will work fine in your controller